# App rejected due to "missing terms and conditions in metadata"

Tags: mac-app-store

I've submitted my app to the App Store and getting rejected because I have to add my terms and conditions to the app metadata. I can't see where to add a link or the text.

I asked the reviewers and they just repeated "add the terms...." without saying where to do so!

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting a link to the terms and conditions in the app description field! This requirement is not documented anywhere as far as I can see. I hope this helps someone else not to waste a few days. :)